# ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(150)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum using ChromeDriver and Chrome with Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I want to open Instagram with **python selenium ChromeDriver** and I have faced with a problem.

```py
import pdb
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

When I run this code:
first Google Chrome opens.Then after a few moments I see this error in **ChromeDriver window**:

> [6108:6244:0824/025032.331:ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(150)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum.

Comment: seems to have something to do with the performance monitor getting disk idle time:  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f0a961b2fb8fcee156fa172b8ad00ce5e95c7a07/chrome/browser/performance_monitor/wmi_refresher.cc

Comment: would you tell me what should i do with this code? I'm just a amateur programmer @pcalkins

Comment: I just figured this might help troubleshoot the issue.  I wouldn't touch the Chromium code.

Comment: I would first check to see if Chrome runs successfully when you launch it manually.  You didn't mention much about the platform, chrome version or chromedriver version.  You may want to add that... and maybe even some details about the disk/partition where Chrome is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
[6108:6244:0824/025032.331:ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(150)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum.
```

...implies that the **Enumeration** of the files failed.

---

This error is defined in [wmi_refresher.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f0a961b2fb8fcee156fa172b8ad00ce5e95c7a07/chrome/browser/performance_monitor/wmi_refresher.cc#134):

```
  long wmi_refresher_enum_id = 0;
  // Add the enumerator for the disk performance data.
  hr = wmi_refresher_config->AddEnum(
      wmi_services_.Get(), L"Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk", 0,
      nullptr, &wmi_refresher_enum_, &wmi_refresher_enum_id);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    LOG(ERROR)
    << "Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum.";
    *res = InitStatus::kRefresherAddEnumError;
    return;
  }
  *res = InitStatus::kInitStatusOk;
  refresh_ready_ = true;
}
```

---

As per the article [Reasons why the error Enumeration of the files failed](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2010/06/18/reasons-why-the-error-enumeration-of-the-files-failed-may-occur-during-system-state-backup/)  this error can occur during due to either of the following factors:

1. A path pointing to a local that no longer exists.
2. An incomplete path (such as \myservice\myservice.exe).
3. A UNC path the service does not understand how to query the folder (such as \myservice\myservice.exe).
4. Invalid characters in the path: Using dots which some application vendors use (such as C:\myservice\bin..\myservice.exe).
5. Syntax formatting of the path: This can be a path that includes space which is not enclosed by double quotes (such as C:\Program Files (x86)\ my service\bin\chromedriver.exe).
6. A valid path on SAN drives of a Failover Cluster: This can be any service(s) in which its path is on the passive node of a Failover Cluster pointing to a Physical Disk resource that is owned by another nodes when error is experienced (such as Z:\folder\app\bin\myservice.exe)

---

### This usecase

I don't see any major issue in your code trial. However you may need to passing the *absolute path* of the **ChromeDriver** through the *Key* **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```